# Getting the local DayOfWeek name for a DateTimeOffset value in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, datetimeoffset, dateadd, datepart

What is the best way to get a *local-time* day name for a `DATETIMEOFFSET` field in SQL Server (2008+)? Is `DATENAME(DW, DATEADD(mi, DATEPART(tz, @dt), @dt))` an acceptable approach to do this? It seems to work but is there a better way?

```
-- this is a Tuesday in London but still a Monday in PST
declare @dt datetimeoffset = '2016-4-12 01:14:00.00000 -08:00'

select TOP(1)
   DATENAME(DW, @dt),
   DATENAME(DW, DATEADD(mi, DATEPART(tz, @dt), @dt)),
   DATENAME(DW, CAST(@dt AS DATETIME))
```

results in

```
Tuesday, Monday, Tuesday
```

The correct answer is `Monday`.

Comment: The value of datetimeoffset `'2016-4-12 01:14:00.00000 -08:00'` means `'2016-4-12 01:14'` at PST, and `'2016-04-12 08:14'` at London, both should be Tuesday

Comment: @Eric Thanks, the MSDN documentation for `DateTimeOffset` was particularly vague on that point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
-- Corrected the value as -01:00
DECLARE @dt datetimeoffset = '2016-4-12 01:14:00.00000 -01:00'
SELECT 
    @dt AS OffSetForLondon,
    DATENAME(DW, @dt) AS WeekNameLondon, -- London (-1:00)
    DATENAME(DW, SWITCHOFFSET(@dt, '-08:00')) AS WeekNamePST -- PST (-8:00)
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually, that value is Tuesday in both Pacific and London time zones, however neither are represented here.  Allow me to explain.

When you read a `datetimeoffset` value, the date and time shown *are* the local time, as reflected by the offset specified.  So, the value you provided is:

```
2016-04-12 01:14:00 -08:00
```

This is Tuesday, April 12th, 2016.  It's 01:14 in *Alaska* time, because of *daylight saving time* being in effect.  Pacific time is actually at -07:00 on this date, so the equivalent value there would be:

```
2016-04-12 02:14:00 -07:00
```

Again, still Tuesday, April 12th.

In UTC, that would be:

```
2016-04-12 09:14:00 +00:00
```

However, this is not the time in London, but rather the time in Iceland.  London is +01:00 on this date, again due to *daylight saving time*.  The equivalent time in London would be:

```
2016-04-12 10:14:00 +01:00
```

Again, still Tuesday.

To answer the actual question you asked, you can simply take the date part directly from the `datetimeoffset` value:

```
declare @dt datetimeoffset = '2016-04-12 01:14:00.00000 -08:00'
select DATENAME(DW, @dt)
```

Also, watch those leading zeros.  ;)

Comment: Thanks. MSDN seemed a bit vague on whether the first part is UTC or local (and yes, I should have picked an earlier date, I was trying to avoid the DST discussion).

Comment: SQL is simply following ISO8601 / RFC3339 standards, which are used all over the place.  In all cases, the date and time value presented are the local values.  To convert to UTC, *subtract* the offset.  When the offset is negative, it may be easier to think of first inverting the sign and then adding.